# iOS 5.1 UIWebView crash the iOS simulator after loading a PDF file

Tags: uiwebview, ios-simulator, ios5.1

I'm developing an universal application with two view controllers, a Master View Controller (a UITableViewController) and a Detail View Controller (with a UIWebView). When the user selects an item (each item is an object with a URL property) in the table, the app sets the detailItem property in the DetailViewController. I customized the setDetailItem to detect when the detailItem is set and open the related URL in the DetailViewController's web view.

The user selects another item and the web view loads the other related URL.

It works fine with items containing URLs targeting HTML files. When the URL targets a PDF file, the web view loads it normally but, when the user selects another item, the app crashes.

On the iPhone simulator it crashes if the user returns to the MasterViewController by pressing the back button in the navigation bar. On the iPad simulator, I'm using a UISplitViewController and it crashes when the user selects any other item in the MasterViewController's table view.

Even setting Xcode to display all exceptions it doesn't show any output. Only crashes in the main.m.

Curiously, if I deploy the app on the device and use it, it works fine, but if I run on the device debugging from Xcode it also crashes.

Any idea on how to fix it or is it just a bug in the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same problem when displaying a PDF in a UIWebview: the simulator crashes, it works fine on devices, though. So it really looks like it could be a bug in the simulator.

BTW: we are using ARC: are you as well?